# Component wise comparision of float values in Numpy is returning wrong result

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am getting wrong results when I do an element wise comparison on a numpy array of floats.

For eg:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(4, 5 + 0.025, 0.025)
print a

mask = a==5.0
print mask

na = a[mask]
print na
```

When I run the above code, a == 5.0 doesn't give me a True value for the
index where the value is in fact 5.0
I also tried setting the dtype of array to numpy.double thinking it could
be a floating point precision issue but it still returns me wrong result.

I am pretty sure I am missing something here....can anyone point me to right direction or tell me what's wrong with the code above?

Thanks!

Comment: As a temporary fix, I have to actually do:  abs(a - 5.0) <0.00001  to get it to give me correct/expected answer but I would still love to know if there is a better way of doing this?

Comment: probably floating point issue, for instance see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: try using `linspace` instead of `arange`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an imprecision here when using float types, use [`np.isclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/generated/numpy.isclose.html) to compare an array against a scalar float value:

```
In [50]:
mask = np.isclose(a,5.0)
print(mask)
na = a[mask]
na

[False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False False False False False False False False False
 False False False False  True False]
Out[50]:
array([ 5.])
```

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to see if there is some function like that. Thanks for the quick answer.

Comment: Actually my build of numpy doesn't have isclose method. But I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: You must be using an old version I suggest upgrading if possible

Comment: I recommend being careful when using functions to make approximations. It is always a good thing to have an epson value which may vary according to your problem.

Comment: @RicardoSilveira `np.isclose` takes an epsilon absolute or relative param, the default is `1e-05` and `1e-08` respectively